# change a property in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, methods, properties, viewcontroller

I've searched how to run a method from another `ViewController` on stackoverflow and didn't find an answer.
I have a `ViewController1` playing an audio using `AVAudioPlayer` and I want my `ViewController2` to be able to change it's volume.

I've tried the basic: calling a method in `ViewController2` that changes the volume in `ViewController1`.
 This doesn't work. The method is able do output Logs but isn't able to change properties.

Thanks

Comment: if you create object of view 1 and then try to change volume then it will not work.

Comment: Could you explain how do you access View Controller 1 from your method in View Controller 2? If you are creating a new View Controller 1 instance, it won't work.

Comment: @veducm thats how I did it. How do I access to the loaded view?

Comment: If you create a new instance of View Controller 1, it will not be the same one that you had. So, if your code requires the view to be loaded, initialized, etc. you should either access the original View Controller 1 instance through the app delegate, a parent view controller or by having a property in View Controller 2 that references the existing View Controller 1.

Comment: @veducm how do I reference the existing View Controller 1?

Comment: Easiest way, before switching to View Controller 2, in View Controller 1 save a reference to self as a property in View Controller 2 (viewController2.refToVC1 = self;). This way, when you need to call the method in View Controller 1 from View Controller 2, you call it from the property in View Controller 2 ([self.refToVC1 method];)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a message from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1`.
For that either use:
1. Notifications
2. Delegation

Here is the link for a tutorial if you are unaware of both of them.
http://devinsheaven.com/cocoa-tutorial-passing-messages-between-objects-notifications-delegates-and-target-action/