# passing the value from one view to other view in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am novice in iOS.. so I have question.
I have 2 views in a UITabBar. one is registration and second one is details.

I want to pass textfields data from registration view to details view. registrations view 
containing textfields .

how can I do it??

Thankss

Comment: You mean u want to pass first tab values into second tab?

Comment: use NSNotification to pass data betwen two tabs..

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968376/change-a-property-in-another-viewcontroller/17968508#17968508
Delegation or Notifications is the way.

Comment: hi, you can use delegation or notification for passing data between two tabs in tabBarController.

Comment: yes kareem... i have to pass one value from 1 to 2nd view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the App Delegate for things that need to be passed around like that.

Create an instance variable in your app delegate to store the value you want to share, e.g.:

```
NSString *name;
```

In your Registration view, store the value into the instance variable in your app delegate:

```
AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ad.name = self.nameField.text;
```

Then in your Details view you can access it by something like:

```
AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.nameLabel.text = ad.name;
```

Alternatively, you could keep a pointer to your Registration view in your app delegate and then just reference that from your Details view and access the text fields directly.

Answer (score 5):

Options:

1. Use global variable: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958944/pass-core-data-entity-variable-between-views/17959309#17959309)
2. Use delegation pattern: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696304/passing-values-from-second-view-to-firstview-in-xcode)
3. Use notification infrastructure: [article](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/09/10/design-patterns-key-value-observing/)
4. Persist the value in app's userdefault storage, then read when you need : [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475300/storing-results-after-screen-is-disappear/16476022#16476022)